# JavaScriptのBabelで特定の機能だけ有効にする

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Babelで特定の機能だけ有効にすることはできるのでしょうか?

arrow functionはすでに実装されているのでそちらを使い、classはまだ実装されていないのでbabelで変換する、というふうにESの機能ごとにbabelのon, offを切り替えることはできるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

最新のBabel(6.7.5 で確認)ではプロジェクトのディレクトリに作成する`.babelrc`で設定する方法が[推奨されています](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/user-handbook.md#toc-babelrc)。
必要な物だけ`presets`や`plugins`に指定します。

```
{
    "presets": [
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-classes",
        "transform-strict-mode"
    ]
}
```

`.babelrc`がなくともツール毎に実行時に指定する方法はあります。
例えばコマンドラインツールだと、オプションで指定出来ます。

```
babel --plugins transform-strict-mode,transform-es2015-classes hello.js
```

しかし、`.babelrc`を作っておけばツール毎に指定する手間がない、という事のようです。

プリセットやプラグインの一覧は http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/ にあります。
[プリセットに`es2015`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/)を指定するとES6をES5に変換する為のプラグインが全て読み込まれるようです。

```json
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```